# How does an EventHandler know to allow = operator only in defining class?

Tags: c#, event-handling

I started with a question, and in typing the question, found the answer, but instead of deleting, I thought it might be helpful to A) get confirmation, and B) help others.

If I have an event, and several places in the application add listeners, what is the best way to remove all listeners at once? For example, I can ...

```
myPage.OnPageOpened += OpenPage;
```

and later in my code ...

```
myPage.OnPageOpened -= OpenPage;
```

But what if I have unknown 3rd party subscribers and I want to press a magic Reset button that clears everything and starts from scratch?

You can use += and -= operators anywhere against the EventHandler, because the operator overloads are public. The = overloaded operator is private it can only be called in the defining class.

So in the defining class I can use this to clear my EventHandler.

```
OnPageOpened = null;
```

And to expose that functionality, I could ...

```
public void ClearPageOpenedEvents() {
   OnPageOpened = null;
}
```

Is that correct?

Comment: Had I had reflector installed / opened, this would have been a lot faster / easier to discover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. The reason for this is that the compiler creates a `private` `delegate` object under the covers, like this:

```
private EventHandler pageOpened;

public EventHandler PageOpened
{
    add { pageOpened += value; }
    remove { pageOpened -= value; }
}
```

Inside your class, you have a reference to the private `delegate` instance, so that's why you can do the assignment. You definitely want to expose a method to clear the targets if that's functionality you need; you don't want to expose the `delegate` itself.

Answer (score 1):

That's the way to do it, but how does something outside the class know that the class should drop all its event listeners? What if someone extending/using your code is expecting that event on an ongoing basis?

Comment: It's during a reset, where the game is starting over. I agree that the public ClearPageOpenedEvents() is not a normal situation, and should be used with caution.

Comment: And should probably (at least in my case) be internal, instead of public.

Comment: Perhaps you could dispose of your objects and create new ones. That would also ensure that you are starting from a clean state. Cleaning up also has the advantage that you won't miss an event handler that needs to be cleared if you extend your class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the assignment operator on an event because that's how adding and removing events work. Using Reflector shines a lot of light on how events are done in C#.

Given the simple class of

```
public class MyClass
{
  public event EventHandler MyEvent;
}
```

The following code is produced when compiled

```
public class MyClass
{
  private EventHandler MyEvent;

  public event EventHandler MyEvent;
}
```

So when you are referencing `MyEvent` you are referring to the private delegate variable `MyEvent`. The `+=` and `-=` operators are "special" (because they aren't operators) and get changed into calling the `add` and `remove` methods that are created for the event (which use the assignment operator themselves).

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
public void add_MyEvent(EventHandler value)
{
  this.MyEvent = (EventHandler) Delegate.Combine(this.MyEvent, value);
}

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
public void remove_MyEvent(EventHandler value)
{
    this.MyEvent = (EventHandler) Delegate.Remove(this.MyEvent, value);
}
```